# Letter Grid Riddle

Tags: word

Not sure where this puzzle is from, but it was sent to me by my little cousin.

[image]

Hint:

> The answer is a 3 letter word.

Super hint:

> From the specified letter, draw lines in alphabetical order

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you provide proper attribution of this puzzle?

Comment: Hello, it is an app called "Who Killed My Sister?"

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 9):

The answer is

> YOU

Because

> If you trace the letters, C to D to E; J to K to L to ...; you will get this:
>  [image]

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: it's connect-the-dots, only with the letters of the alphabet.